# LSTM, Keras - Plot of Loss on the Train and Test Datasets

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, lstm

I'm using LSTM to train a multivariate time-series model to forecast value.
after I train/test split and reshape the data, I train the model and the "Loss on the Train and Test" having very big gap which mean the error is a lot.

**Question : How to reduce/minimize the error gap between Train and Test?**

Training Network 1

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(5278, input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2]), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
model.summary()


EPOCHS = 10


history = model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=EPOCHS, batch_size=15, validation_data=(test_X, test_y), verbose=1, shuffle=False)

plt.plot(history.history['loss'], label='train')
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'], label='test')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[big gap in the loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1r5N.png)

Comment: What is your programming question?

Comment: Oooh ya...
the question is...
How to reduce / minimize the error in between? As you can see from the picture it's too big gap.

Comment: Sorry, that's not a programming question. Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for what is on-topic here.